# jquery change text of all previous labels

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML

```
<div class="main_holder">
  <div class="input_holder">
    <label for="something">Some Label</label><br/>
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" class="cat_textbox" id="field_input" name="somename" /> 
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>

  <div class="input_holder">
    <label for="something">Some Label</label><br/>
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" class="cat_textbox" id="field_input" name="somename" /> 
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>

  <div class="input_holder">
    <label for="something">Some Label</label><br/>
        <input type="text" maxlength="255" class="cat_textbox" id="field_input" name="somename" /> 
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery

```
var increment=1;
$('a.add').click(function() {
  increment++;

  $(this).prev('input_holder').clone().insertBefore(this).prevAll('label').text(increment);

  return false;
});
```

My idea is when i clone a field i want that field to show which exactly it is(is it 1,2,3 etc). The problem is that i cant grab the labels that are before the button i have clicked on.

Comment: did you mean selector '.input_holder'?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `closest()` instead of `prevAll()` , like this:

```
var increment=0;
$('a.add').click(function() {
  increment++;

  $(this).prev('.input_holder').clone().insertBefore(this).closest('.input_holder').find('label').text(increment);

  return false;
});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8nmMp/)

**UPDATE:**
This is a new version that places an attribute on each `.input_holder` to hold its increment:

```
$('a.add').click(function() {

   prevholder = $(this).prev('.input_holder');
   increment = prevholder.attr('data-increment');
   increment++;
   prevholder.attr('data-increment', increment);
   prevholder.clone().insertBefore(this).closest('.input_holder').find('label').text(increment);

   return false;
});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8nmMp/1/)

Comment: it doesnt work cause if u click add on the next field it will continue incrementing from the prev and i want every field to start from 1

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer with a new version that keeps individual increments per `.input_holder` , they are saved in an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/GpT2x/

```
$('a.add').click(function() {
  var val = $(this).prev('.input_holder').find('label:last').text();
  val = val == "Some Label" ? 1 : (parseInt(val) + 1);
     $(this).prev('.input_holder').clone().insertBefore(this).closest('.input_holder').find('label').text(val);

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate the input blocks into another div. This gives you the opportunity to write some simpler javascript code.

HTML

```
<div class="main_holder">
  <div class="block_holder">
    <div class="input_holder">
      <label for="something">Some Label</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" maxlength="255" class="cat_textbox" id="field_input"
      name="somename" />
    </div> <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>

  </div>
  <div class="block_holder">
    <div class="input_holder">
      <label for="something">Some Label</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" maxlength="255" class="cat_textbox" id="field_input"
      name="somename" />
    </div> <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>

  </div>
  <div class="block_holder">
    <div class="input_holder">
      <label for="something">Some Label</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" maxlength="255" class="cat_textbox" id="field_input"
      name="somename" />
    </div> <a href="#" class="add">Add+</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".main_holder").on("click", "a.add", function () {
    var count = $(this).closest(".block_holder").find("label").length;
    $(this).prev(".input_holder").clone().insertBefore($(this)).find("label").html(count);
    return false;
});
```

Example see here: http://jsfiddle.net/StJwC/

By the way, you should differ the name of the input fields and use different ids for valid HTML code.